# How to Exclude Tags <script> Being Moved to Bottom magento 2.3

Tags: magento2

In my Magento site, we found there was configuration in admin.

```
Admin -> Store -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer (Enabled only on Developer mode). JavaScript settings -> Move JS code to the bottom of the page
```

When this is **`YES`**, all the scripts tags on the site moves to the bottom of the page.

But I need to include a script which shouldn't move to the bottom.

My scripts loads in via **`.phtml`**. And I need to load avoid that particular script from moving to bottom

[image]

this is code from `magento/module-bundle/view/frontend/templates/catalog/product/view/summary.phtml` i have issue product summary on bundle product not showing

Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: check this link - https://fishpig.co.uk/magento/extensions/page-speed/exclude-tags/

Comment: @MohitPatel not working, i have tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so in the end, i choose to create mixin js for product-summary.js

```
define([
    'jquery',
    'mage/template',
    'jquery-ui-modules/widget',
    'Magento_Bundle/js/price-bundle'
], function ($, mageTemplate) {
    'user strict';

    return function(productSummary) {
        $.widget('mage.productSummary', productSummary, {
            _renderOption: function (key, row) {
                var template;
                if (row && row.length > 0 && row[0] !== null) {
                    template = $('[data-template="bundle-summary"]').html();
                    template = mageTemplate($.trim(template), {
                        data: {
                            _label_: this.cache.currentElement.options[key].title
                        }
                    });
                    this.cache.currentKey = key;
                    this.cache.summaryContainer = $(template);
                    this.element.append(this.cache.summaryContainer);
                    $.each(row, this._renderOptionRow.bind(this));
                    this.cache.currentElementCount += row.length;
                    //Reset Cache
                    this.cache.currentKey = null;
                }
            },

            _renderOptionRow: function (key, optionIndex) {
                var template;
                template = $('[data-template="bundle-option"]').html();
                template = mageTemplate($.trim(template), {
                    data: {
                        _quantity_: this.cache.currentElement.options[this.cache.currentKey].selections[optionIndex].qty,
                        _label_: this.cache.currentElement.options[this.cache.currentKey].selections[optionIndex].name
                    }
                });
                this.cache.summaryContainer
                    .find(this.options.optionSelector)
                    .append(template);

            }
        });
        return $.mage.productSummary;
    }
});
```

and don't forget add config to requirejs-config.js

cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at **vendor/magento/module-theme/Controller/Result/JsFooterPlugin.php** you see the regex.

It seems if you would add type or id to script tag it will exclude your script from moving to the place before closing body tag. Other option would be to modify this class.

Question is how you are adding exactly your JS that you want to exclude?

Comment: add id or type to script tag not working

Comment: can you show some code? how you added and where?

Comment: i have just update my question

Comment: Those examples shouldn't change anything when moved to the bottom. What side effect it has that you don't want it to move to the bottom ?

Comment: in another project script not move to the bottom, so i assumse issue related that. it caused summary information not showing
https://ibb.co/sCJHTsP (ss project script not move)
https://ibb.co/n6GJMcN (ss project script move bottom)

Comment: You are right. product-summary.js file from module-bundle is looking for templates inside default  `summaryContainer:  '[data-container="product-summary"]'`. So if script tags with templates are moved to the bottom the product-summary widget can't find them. It seems like this case is not covered and should be verified and reported on github.  Altough it seems you can try to change summaryContainer option and/or modify this product-summary.js script to make it work.

Comment: exactly , i have just update my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Override entire controller method - beforeSendResponseMake in Magento\Theme\Controller\Result\JsFooterPlugin
2. Add extra tag in your script tag to skip the regex

   `<script[^>]*+(?<!text/x-magento-template.)>. *?</script>`

So just add "text/x-magento-template" in your script tag. Make sure you dont use type="" attribute, and make sure its the last attribute without any space after, eg:

`<script src="xyz.js" exclude-this-tag="text/x-magento-template"></script>`